# React functional prop is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My parent component is where I have a function I pass to the child component:
NOTE: Planetdata does not have Redirect but I dont think that shoukd matter

```
export default function LandingPage() {
    function redirection(){
      console.log("redirecting");
    }
    
    return(
        <>
         ...
        {planetData.map((planet) => (
          <Planet planet={planet} key={planet.id} Redirect={redirection}/>
        ))}
        <Lights />
      </Canvas>
    </>
    )
}
```

My child component where I want to call the function from:

```
export default function Planet({ planet: { color, xRadius, zRadius, size, speed, offset,Name = "",Redirect,...props} }) {
  
    return (
      <>
        <mesh ref={planetRef} onClick={(e) => {
          this.Redirect(); //CALLING IT HERE
        }}>
          <sphereGeometry args={[size, 32, 32]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
          {Name != "" && <Html prepend distanceFactor={65}>
            <div className="annotation">{Name}</div>
          </Html> }     
        </mesh>
        <Eliptical xRadius={xRadius} zRadius={zRadius} />
      </>
    );
  }
```

I tried it without this in child component. The error I get is Redirect is not a function

Descriptive error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: redirect is not a function
    at Planet (Planet.js:25)
    at renderWithHooks (react-reconciler.development.js:6412)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-reconciler.development.js:9238)
    at beginWork (react-reconciler.development.js:10476)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-reconciler.development.js:12184)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-reconciler.development.js:12233)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-reconciler.development.js:12292)
    at beginWork$1 (react-reconciler.development.js:16531)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-reconciler.development.js:15337)
    at workLoopSync (react-reconciler.development.js:15268)
    at renderRootSync (react-reconciler.development.js:15231)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-reconciler.development.js:14840)
    at react-reconciler.development.js:2546
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority (react-reconciler.development.js:2495)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-reconciler.development.js:2541)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-reconciler.development.js:2528)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-reconciler.development.js:14421)
    at Object.updateContainer (react-reconciler.development.js:18229)
    at render (react-three-fiber.esm.js:1568)
    at react-three-fiber.esm.js:1370
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:20573)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:20634)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:23426)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:23151)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:22990)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22329)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139)
    at ResizeObserver.callback (web.js:69)
    at later (index.js:27)
```

Comment: `this.Redirect();` should just be `Redirect`

Comment: add react-three-fiber as tag please, yes dont call `Redirect()` just pass it

Comment: Does not matter if I do this.Redirect or Redirect I still get error

Comment: Fix the typo in the code in your snippet, i.e. `this.Redirect()` to `redirect()` and then ensure this is the place throwing the error. From what I can see, the code is syntactically correct other than for the typo with using `this` in a function component. Can you update your question to include the full error message and any accompanying stacktrace?

Comment: @DrewReese updated it with the stacktrace

Comment: Are you attempting to execute `redirect` instead of `Redirect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Redirect` was passed directly as a prop:

```
<Planet
  planet={planet}
  key={planet.id}
  Redirect={redirection} // <-- passed as prop
/>
```

You are attempting to destructure `Redirect` prop from the `planet` prop object. In other words, you are trying to access it a level too deep.

```
export default function Planet({
  planet: {
    color,
    xRadius,
    zRadius,
    size,
    speed,
    offset,
    Name = "",
    Redirect, // <-- undefined is not a function!
    ...props
  },
  // <-- but should be here
}) {
```

You likely meant to destructure `Redirect` from props and also to spread the rest of the props into `props` instead of the rest of `planet`. Move these out to the root prop level.

Also, as pointed out comments above, remove the `this` as `this` isn't defined in function components.

```
export default function Planet({
  planet: { color, xRadius, zRadius, size, speed, offset,Name = ""},
  Redirect,
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <>
      <mesh ref={planetRef} onClick={Redirect}>
        <sphereGeometry args={[size, 32, 32]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
        {Name != "" && <Html prepend distanceFactor={65}>
          <div className="annotation">{Name}</div>
        </Html> }     
      </mesh>
      <Eliptical xRadius={xRadius} zRadius={zRadius} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: any solution you have in mind? Lol sorry kinda a beginner at this. So redirect outside of planet is the solution?

Comment: @cutecucumber Yes, move `Redirect` out so it's destructured from props and not `planet`.

Comment: @cutecucumber Looks like you moved it all the way out of the props object you're destructuring from. Should be between the closing `}` from `planet` and the closing `})` of the function signature.

Comment: Does not work lol i dont understand why it still does not recognize it as a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239223/discussion-between-cute-cucumber-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to call that function,
you can replace this code,

```
<mesh ref={planetRef} onClick={(e) => {
          this.Redirect(); //CALLING IT HERE
        }}>
```

to this, it will work, dont call function, just pass it, you dont even need fat arrow,

```
<mesh ref={planetRef} onClick={Redirect}}>
```

Comment: Nope did not work. I dont think that would work cause you are not calling it

Comment: @cutecucumber because you're passing the callback to the `onClick` prop of `mesh`, it gets _executed_ when a click event fires on `mesh`.

Comment: I tried it, but it would not call the function. I can tell by the console.log() statement I have in my function